# Laptop audio suddenly non-existent, does not work anywhere

Tags: windows-7, laptop, audio

So I'm trying to get my laptop's onboard speakers to work again. They were working fine one day, then after a reboot, they simply disappeared. This problem has been ongoing for about a month.

This is on Windows 7 x64 Professional. The laptop is a MSI GX620.

- The sound does not play from either the speakers or the headphone jack.
- The onboard mic does not work, either.
- There absolutely nothing regarding either my speakers or mic in the device manager under the Sound category.
- Doing a "Scan for hardware changes" brings up nothing.
- No devices are listed under "Playback devices" or "Recording devices" in my computer's sound properties.
- I have tried to install every audio driver known to mankind with no luck.
- There are no BIOS settings regarding audio or onboard audio at all.
- I have booted to a Linux Mint LiveCD, and the sound properties are also missing the audio.
- HDMI audio and USB sound cards do work, but are inconvenient.
- The warranty is expired, and even if it wasn't, it would be voided since I have a new HDD installed (months ago; unrelated to the current problem).

As far as my motherboard is concerned, I somehow completely removed all traces of any integrated sound from it.

I've done everything I could think of. Anyone have any ideas?

Even though I've tried a LiveCD with no luck, is it possible that a full reformat of Windows could fix the issue?

Comment: It sounds to me like your sound card just quit on you.  If neither Windows nor a LiveCD can detect anything, it probably isn't there.

Comment: Clear the cmos on the motherboard, then enter the bios and set the date and time before windows loads, see if this does anything.

Comment: what commands did you try on the livecd? does it turn up on lspci or lshw?